# JSON file opens in new tab (I want to download)

Tags: html, json, google-chrome, download

I have an anchor tag

```html
<a target="_blank" href="./assets/.../sample.json" download="">Download Sample JSON</a>
```

If I use download attribute: it shows - Failed / Network Error

If I do not use download attribute: it opens the `.json` in new tab

**Expected result : .json should be downloaded**

---

I also have another anchor tag for CSV

```html
<a target="_blank" href="./assets/.../sample.csv" download="">Download Sample CSV</a>
```

which perfectly downloads `.csv` every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually can't download a JSON file like that. You need some javascript. So add in

```
<a target="_blank" href="./assets/.../sample.json" download="" onClick="downloadJSON">Download Sample JSON</a>
```

and then in your js file or  tags in your html add in:

```
  function downloadJSON(){

 var json = JSON.stringify(yourJSON);
 
        
        json = [json];
        var blobForYou = new Blob(json, { type: "application/JSON" });
         FileSaver.SaveAs(blobForYou);
}
```

Comment: ok, but i am curious then : how does csv gets downloaded without blob OR filesaver ?